# Rails "share documents" starting application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, share, documents

I am currently working on an application that have an ActiveRecord called Template.

I would like users to be able to

- "share" Templates so that everyone with a link could see them
- give "view" or "edit" rigths to specific users
- or keep the template only to himself

I am sure this problem should have been solved many times and I am wondering if anyone has heard of something we could start from? Something like a simple working document sharing application?

Comment: What you're describing is the core business logic for an app. While your question "is there something we can start from" might be answerable, I haven't heard of anything like that. Answering "how do you do this" is an extremely broad question, which would be better answered by you working through a rails tutorial book. I don't think you're going to get the answer you're hoping for here.

Comment: The business logic is that Template is a file with some metadata. I would like to configure the permissions on this objects on how could view or edit it. I was really hoping for a gem or scaffold that would give us the object, the connections with the user, the form for editing the permissions.